# Oracle SQL Query to get distinct result using like

Tags: sql, oracle

| ID | VERSION_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | ABC1234.1 |
| 222 | ABC1234.2 |
| 333 | ABC12345.1 |
| 444 | ABC12345.2 |
| 555 | ABC123456.1 |
| 666 | ABC123457.1 |

I have an oracle table in the above structure. I want to get unique result with **version_id** column like 'ABC%.%. For example for version_id ABC1234.* I should get result with Id 111(least one).

The final Result should be in below format.

| ID | VERSION_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | ABC1234.1 |
| 333 | ABC12345.1 |
| 555 | ABC123456.1 |
| 666 | ABC123457.1 |

Comment: It looks as though all version_ids match 'ABC%.%' unless I am missing something, so I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Will the first version_id always be dot-1, and, could you ever have dot-10+?

Comment: `VERSION_ID like 'ABC%.1'` ?

Comment: @Isolated First version can start from anything, say it can start from even dot-2. But I need the result for minimum one.

Comment: Why 'using LIKE'? None of the answers so far use LIKE, and it's not clear how it could be used.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the solution below for that purpose.

```sql
WITH YourSample (ID, VERSION_ID) AS 
(
  SELECT 111, 'ABC1234.1'   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 222, 'ABC1234.2'   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 333, 'ABC12345.1'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 444, 'ABC12345.2'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 555, 'ABC123456.1' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 666, 'ABC123457.1' FROM dual
)
SELECT 
    MIN(ID)KEEP(dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY ID) ID
  , MIN(VERSION_ID)KEEP(dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY ID) VERSION_ID
FROM YourSample t
GROUP BY SUBSTR( VERSION_ID, 1, INSTR(VERSION_ID, '.')-1 )
ORDER BY ID;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/x2mMBhZ-)

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from the question:
the rows where version_id is the MIN( version_id )
among the rows where version_id LIKE 'ABC%.%' and grouping by SUBSTR(version_id,1, INSTR(version_id,'.',-1) - 1)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WITH dat AS 
(
  SELECT 111 AS ID, 'ABC1234.1' AS VERSION_ID   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 222, 'ABC1234.2'   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 333, 'ABC12345.1'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 444, 'ABC12345.2'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 555, 'ABC123456.1' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 666, 'ABC123457.1' FROM dual
)
SELECT MIN(ID),REGEXP_REPLACE(VERSION_ID,'\.[0-9]+$','')
  FROM dat
 GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(VERSION_ID,'\.[0-9]+$','')
 ORDER BY MIN(ID);
```